# Graphene input error for Pydantic models with discriminator while generating Input object schema

Tags: python, validation, graphql, pydantic, graphene-django

I am using pydantic validations for my requirements and it uses `discriminator`. I am writing GraphQL APIs and want to convert those pydantic models into graphene input objects.

Below is my code.

```
from graphene_pydantic import PydanticInputObjectType, PydanticObjectType
import graphene
from typing import Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Cat(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['cat']
    meows: int


class Dog(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['dog']
    barks: float


class Lizard(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['reptile', 'lizard']
    scales: bool


class Model(BaseModel):
    pet: Union[Cat, Dog, Lizard] = Field(..., discriminator='pet_type')
    n: int


print(Model(pet={'pet_type': 'dog', 'barks': 3.14, 'eats': 'biscuit'}, n=1))


class Input(PydanticInputObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        # exclude specified fields
        exclude_fields = ("id",)


class Output(PydanticObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        # exclude specified fields
        exclude_fields = ("id",)


class CreateAnimal(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        input = Input()

    output = Output

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(parent, info, input):
        print(input)
        # save model here
        return input


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    createPerson = CreateAnimal.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(mutation=Mutation)
print(schema)
```

I tried by commenting on the `discriminator` code and it's working fine but I need those validations for graphql also. If I run that code it's throwing the below error.

```
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\graphql\type\definition.py", line 1338, in fields    raise TypeError(f"{self.name} fields cannot be resolved. {error}")
TypeError: Input fields cannot be resolved. The input field type must be a GraphQL input type.
```

Can someone help me with this?

I am using [graphene-pydantic](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-pydantic) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i havent tested your code but i think this what you need:

```py
class CreateAnimal(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        input = graphene.Argument(Input)

    output = graphene.Field(Output)
```

Comment: I tried that but received `TypeError: Expected Graphene type, but received: Placeholder(<class '__main__.Cat'>).` As per [pydantic](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-pydantic) documentation, this code should work I think. If I remove `discriminator` from the model, its works perfectly. But I need to handle validations again on the backend.